# convert xml to objects java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I would appreciate your help, how can I match such xmls data in java with different tags, for example can come: <t: UserAttrs>, <ns3: UserAttrs>, <ns37: UserAttrs>
values can be different between "<" and "UserAttrs>"
I need to extract everything that is in the tag

```
<Rtp xmlns="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran.xsd">
<Tran>
    <t:Request InitiatorRid="ECACS2oob" Kind="TProcessA" LifePhase="Single" NetworkRid="V"
               OrigTime="2022-07-06T08:04:00" ProcessorRid="Name" ProcessorInstId="1" OriginatorInterfaceId="1308"
               xmlns=""
               xmlns:ct=""
               xmlns:t=""
               xmlns:tc="">
        <t:Parties>
            <t:Term AcquirerRid="4005"><t:Caps Interactive="true"/><t:Owner Country="0" Rid="test" Title="test"                                                                                   Url="https://xxx" Mcc="3000"/>
            </t:Term>
        </t:Parties>
        <t:UserAttrs>
            <ct:ParamValue Rid="Reason">         <ct:Val>Authe</ct:Val>
            </ct:ParamValue>
            <ct:ParamValue Rid="EndTime">         <ct:Val>2022-07-06T15:04:00.462</ct:Val>
            </ct:ParamValue>
        </t:UserAttrs>
    </t:Request>
</Tran>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javax.xml.bind` to unmarshall it and ignore tag namespace. Assume `UserAttrs` is your object class:

```
class UserAttrs {
    @XmlElement(name = "ParamValue")
    private List<ParamValue> paramValue;
}

class ParamValue {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Rid")
    private String rId;
}
...
```

Use unmashaller:

```
var ctxUserAttrs = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserAttrs.class);
var inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
var reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(yourXml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
// use reader.hasNext(), reader.next(), reader.nextTag() to navigate to your UserAttrs tag
var unmarshaller = ctxUserAttrs.createUnmarshaller();
var userAttrs = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader, UserAttrs.class).getValue();
```

Code is untested, edit to fit your situation. I'm using akarta.xml.bind-api 2.3.3.